# I want to add a custom png image instead of glyphicon in admin menu section in opencart 2.3x and 3x?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module, opencart2.3

how do i update this, in column_left controller?

```
 if ($catalog) {
      $data['menus'][] = array(
     'id'       => 'menu-catalog',
     'icon'    => 'fa-tags', 
     'name'    => $this->language->get('text_catalog'),
     'href'     => '',
     'children' => $catalog
     );     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't because it is hardcoded for evey menu,

and even you manage to get this done , some other extension you installed still need that update fix

in column left controller
'icon'    => 'fa-tags',  chaange it to 'icon'    => 'glyphicon glyphicon-user'

nothing to change in view , it will work ,

Answer (score 0):

You should customize the html in "admin/view/template/common/column_left.twig"

For example .. replace this code :

```
{% if menu.href %}<a href="{{ menu.href }}"><i class="fa {{ menu.icon }} fw"></i> {{ menu.name }}</a>
```

by:

```
{% if menu.href %}{% if menu.img %}<a href="{{ menu.href }}"><img src="{{ menu.img }}"> {{ menu.name }}</a>{% else %}<a href="{{ menu.href }}"><i class="fa {{ menu.icon }} fw"></i> {{ menu.name }}</a>{% endif %}
```

and adding the image path in menu array item in column_left controller :

```
'img' => 'view/image/file.png'
```